# develop an app which automatically fill the login form and try's to login

Tags: authentication, web, autologin

I want to develop an app which can login to a website (personal website) with a help of single click ,  assuming having all the code from target website . I need to know the abstract or technique to do so.

Answer (score 0):

One common technique is to issue a POST request to the website containing the login information. The website will read the POST variable and extract the login information, proceeding to validation.

For increased security, you should also use HTTPS protocol (which, depending on the platform, may or may not be a complicated process).

You can use front-end Javascript to easily build that POST request using XMLHttpRequest.

Look this [old sample](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php)